# How to Import data into SQL Server using Data Loader

Tags: data-loader

How to integrate SQL Server and import data into a SQL Server database table directly from Salesforce using the Data Loader.

Can anyone provide me steps to solve this..

Thanks,

Comment: see if this answer in salesforce success community helps https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&id=90630000000gt2AAAQ

Answer (score 1):

Directly not possible without third party tools like Informatica or Jitterbit etc .But a two step process might work :

1. Export object records into seperate csv files .
2. Using SQL Server Import wizard you may import those csv's into your SQL environment .

Answer (score 0):

Hey Dataloader is used for loading data into Salesforce only.
You need to use Talend (Open Source Tool) or Jitterbit or any other ETL tools to transfer data between systems.

Answer (score 0):

See your dataloader sample files.  You can Update, Upsert, Extract, Insert data into/out of Salesforce from Sqlserver.  I do it hourly for most jobs and some jobs every minute.